# Filling in form on website?

Tags: python, html, forms, textarea

I't trying to use data from a website in my python code, what I need to do (and also where I'm stuck) is to fill in a form in a website ( `textarea id="input" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>` )
and click a button to get response from site in form of XML schema.

While parsing a schema is not a problem, I have no idea how to get it from this website in my code, would be thankful for any tips for that.

Comment: Take a look at [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

Comment: Depending on your needs, also consider [splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a wrapper for selenium.